Build system for development environment
I have a Next.js/Node.js project that consists of sub-packages. Now I am in the process of separating all code into federated modules. There is many packages already and will be more.
So many, that it will be impossible to manage them in my IDE (IntelliJ).
What are some GUIs for managing and building the modules in development environment
Thank you.
